# Can we prove this without contradiction?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

For real $a,b,c,d,e$, given

$$ ax^2 + (b+c)x + (d+e) = 0$$ has real roots in $[0,1]$.

We need to prove that

$$ ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0$$

has at least one real root.

I was trying to do this by using calculus(Intermediate theorem, for example) but in the solution, it was done using contradiction after writing the latter in terms of former polynomials.

I would like to know if there is any other way to prove this.

Comment: Note in this domain x can only shrink things and shrink with increasing powers